# Contextual actions in mobile/ios best practices

Tags: mobile, ios, menu, actions, popover

UX noob here...

I am trying to envision the vest way to present the user with actions he/she can perform in specific views of my iOS application.

Each view could have different actions.

I have seen a few apps (e.g., Google Calendar, Snapseed) implementing something similar to this:

[image: Mockups with Balsamiq Mockups]

Or alternatively this:

[image: Mockups with Balsamiq Mockups]

I there a particular name for these menus?

What is the best practice/approach for them in mobile apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @adriennetacke for pointing me in the right direction. Following his answer I found [this article](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#) in Google's material design guidelines. It's worth reading it, but for my case the interesting bits were:

- Only one floating action button is recommended per screen to represent the most common action.
- Floating actions should have positive actions like Create, Favorite, Share, Navigate, and Explore (no minor and/or destructive actions).
- As a general rule, have at least three options upon press but not more than six, including the original floating action button target.
- Floating action buttons don’t contain app bar icons or status bar notifications. Don’t layer badges or other elements over a floating action button.

Answer (score 1):

In [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) they are called [`Fixed Action Buttons`](http://materializecss.com/buttons.html) or FABs. Sometimes they also call them `Floating` buttons.

So far, and completely in my experience, they have been great to quickly access menus in mobile apps.

Comment: Awesome, your answer pointed me in the right direction towards this article: https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html Thanks!

Comment: Nice, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a confusion. The add button should open a form where you can add some information when is displayed like the most important button on the page. The symbol "+" don't suggest a menu.

I used this approach, with a menu in the corner in a concept that you can see here https://dribbble.com/shots/2244029-Music-app-concept-design. I also liked a circular menu opened on the full with of page, here: http://www.ios.uplabs.com/search?q=circular%20menu%20ios.

I find easy to open a menu from the corner with one hand and I think is ok for ios. I don't think this is a menu specific to material design.